# Query String checks checkbox on different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, checkbox

I'm having a problem, I have a button on page1 that when clicked passes this url:

http://www.example.com/page1.html?jquery=blogger

once it's clicked will go to page2 where there are checkboxes. I need the checkbox associated with "blogger" (named: cf_538) to be checked once the page loads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var koko = querySt("jquery");


if (koko == 'blogger'){


document.order.cf_538.checked = true;

alert('thank you for showing interest in our start up package');

}else{

alert('thank you for showing interest in our services');

} 

-->
</script>
```

However when I do this, nothing happens but the alert. The check box is not checked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Hal

Comment: You're going to have to provide considerably more information in order for anybody to help.  What does the markup look like?

Answer (score 2):

By "named cf_538" do you mean the `name` attribute?

If so:

```
$("[name=cf_538]").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the topic marked jQuery:

```
$('input[name=cf_538]').attr('checked', true);
```

and is 'order' the name of your form? Your

```
document.order.cf_538.checked = true;
```

would work in the case of

```
<form name="order">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cf_538" />
</form>
```

--

```
document.getElementById('order').cf_538.checked = true;
```

would work in the case of

```
<form id="order">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cf_538" />
</form>
```